# How to save events in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made an app in Tkinter and I am running into a few problems. So when I click a button a function should perform every 1 millisecond. However, once I exit the program and open it again, the computer forgets that I already clicked the button before and does not run the function automatically. I have to click the button again for the function to work. Is there a way for the computer to remember that I already clicked the button?

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def declareFunction():
    print("Hello World")

def runFunction():
    declareFunction()
    root.after(1, runFunction)

button = Button(root, text="Example", command=runFunction)

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way for the computer to remember that I clicked the button, and run the function forever without me clicking on it again?

Comment: When you say "exit the program", do you mean exit tkinter window or entire program?

Comment: If you want the program to remember the state between executions, you need to make it persistent, e.g. write it to a file with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: #Leonardo, I meant exit out of the whole thing

Comment: @Skcoder Should your function still run if the application was closed?

Comment: No, it should not run after the application is closed. But once its opened it should run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only way round this is to save that information (that the button has been clicked) to a file or database because the computer forgets everything about the program once you exit out of it. To make the data persistent there needs to be some external file or DB. Now there are so many options on storing data.

A few of them are [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) , [Shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) , Plain text files, Databases like [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) or better.

I will demonstrate what you want to do with plain text file.(must read docs to know about functionalities that these modules provide)

## Using Plain Text files

The easiest of them.

Create a file, store `False` in there (to indicate button has not been clicked). When the button is clicked the first time, change the file contents from `False` to `True` and call the function. When the program loads up, read the file, see the contents.
If it says `True`, just run the function (and disable the button to prevent clicking as it's already been clicked. ). If it says `False`, just write your usual program.

**NOTE** you might want to `disable` the button to prevent clicking again as the function will just keep on running. Else up to your needs.

Example

```
import tkinter as tk


def declareFunction():
    print('LoL')
    
def runFunction():
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('True')

    # you might wanna disable the button here as well.
    declareFunction()
    root.after(1, runFunction)


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
        d = f.read()
        if d == '':   # write False to file as it is empty
            f.seek(0)
            f.write('False')
            f.truncate()
            root = tk.Tk()
            tk.Button(root, text='Run Function', command=runFunction).pack()
            root.mainloop()

        elif d == 'False':  # if file says False - button was not clicked so create one
            root = tk.Tk()
            tk.Button(root, text='Run Function', command=runFunction).pack()
            root.mainloop()

        elif d == 'True':   # if file says True - button has been clicked
            root = tk.Tk()
            runFunction()    # run the function already as button was clicked
            # disable the button to prevent clicking again
            tk.Button(root, text='run function', state=tk.DISABLED, command=runFunction).pack()
            root.mainloop()
```